# Add value to existing field value db_update

Tags: 7

How can Add value to existing value of field using db_update ?

I have a field in custom table amount which will be incremented by a function

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this:

```
db_update('custom_table')
  ->expression('count', 'count + 1')
  ->condition('id', $id)
  ->execute();
```